# Why classes generated from xml are deprecated?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, deprecated

I have some classes which are generated from xml. For example :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = { "key", "name"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "caData")
public class CaData {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String key;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String name;
}
```

and when I try to use them somewhere

```
private CaData caData;
```

or pass them as a parameter

```
public construct(String name, CaData caData) {
    this.caData = caData;
    this.name = name;
}
```

I get the notifier:

> The type CaData is deprecated.

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a different CaData class on your classpath?

Comment: Try print your cdata class full class name, then you will know which cdata class you are using now.

Comment: I am using the only CaData class, and the problem is for all the generated classes not only for this one.

Comment: I suppose you mean classes generated from XML *Schema*? Can you describe how? - You should see the annotation '@Deprecated` preceding the class header of class CaData. Since you haven't added this, I assume it isn't there, which means that there *is* another class CaData. What happens if you edit CaData.java and insert a syntax error? Is it shown in your IDE?

Comment: I found the problem. The annotation was in my package-info.java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what causes the problem. :) When the classes are generated a class called package-info.java also appears. It looks like:

```
/**
 * Package with jaxb auto-generated for schema ca-config.xsd.
 */
@Deprecated
package com.....config.xml;
```

Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: But the next time you regenerate, this will pop back into existence.  Are you using JAXB to generate java code from XSD files?